# ASP.NET Core, query string to object programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I know that in ASP.NET Core it is possible to automatically convert some query string to an object using special model binding attributes - [FromRoute], [FromQuery] and so on.

Is it possible to perform such a conversion manually? Something like:

```
var queryString = Request.QueryString;
var obj = SomeMagic.QueryStringToObject<MyClass>(queryString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers.parsequery?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to parse a query string into a dictionary.

If you want the actual same behavior as provided by the `[FromQuery]` attribute I'd look at the [`QueryParameterValueSupplier.RenderParametersFromQueryString`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Components/Components/src/Routing/QueryParameterValueSupplier.cs#L53) method, which does most of the heavy-lifting. I'm not sure if this is meant to be used outside of the existing ASP.NET Core framework infrastructure.

Note that a query string is just a collection of string-based name-value pairs. There's no standard that dictates how this should be mapped to something more complex like a Java or C# class. So frameworks like ASP.NET Core build their own convention on top of that, in order to make their complex binding mechanisms work. (e.g. `foo.bar[2]=123`). ASP.NET Core actually has two ways of binding query strings to a model (the "MVC" way and the "jQuery" way), see [`JQueryKeyValuePairNormalizer`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/JQueryKeyValuePairNormalizer.cs#L42).

```
    // This is a helper method for Model Binding over a JQuery syntax.
    // Normalize from JQuery to MVC keys. The model binding infrastructure uses MVC keys.
    // x[] --> x
    // [] --> ""
    // x[12] --> x[12]
    // x[field]  --> x.field, where field is not a number
    private static string NormalizeJQueryToMvc(StringBuilder builder, string key)
```

Finally on a personal note I tend to avoid the query string for anything more complex than simple name-value pairs. When you start to pull in more complex data structures you also run into many limitations. For instance: differentiating between `null` and empty strings; awkward syntax for handling collections; etc. If I really must use the query string for passing along complex data structures, I fallback to a single Base64 encoded JSON-string and handle that manually within my code.

Comment: Of course, but this approach works with simple query strings only (eg. firstName=John&lastName=Doe) and does not support complex object model binding (firstName=John&lastName=Doe&address.country=USA&address.city=Boston&phone[0]=5555555555).

Comment: Ah gotcha, I'll edit the answer. I'm not sure if there's a utility method or class you can use to give you the same behavior.. but maybe you can directly call `QueryParameterValueSupplier.RenderParametersFromQueryString` which is the same mechanism used internally by ASP.NET Core to handle `[FromQuery]` attributes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I'm also looking for a possibility to reuse ASP.NET Core model binder, but don't know how to do that. In ASP.NET MVC 5 there was a class named DefaultModelBinder but there is no analog in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: You're right I think if you want to do this manually you'd need both the mechanism for parsing the query string *and* a mechanism from projecting those key-value pairs to actual C# types (including complex types like custom model classes). I see ASP.NET Core has a `DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext` https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/DefaultModelBindingContext.cs#L223

Comment: Wow! I was managed to get an instance of IModelBinderFactory from services collection but stuck on a task to initialize and properly populate IModelBinder context. And I just didn't notice that static method!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found more generic solution than just parsing a query string. Here I get an instance of IModelBinder (actually an instance of ComplexObjectModelBinder) and use that as a service.

```
// DTO
//
public class PersonName
{
    public string FirstName { get;set; }
    public string LastName { get;set; }
}



// Action handler
// Here I want to convert HTTP request to an instance of PersonName manually
// Example: /SearchByName?LastName=Doe&FirstName=John
//
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchByName(
  [FromServices] IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider,
  [FromServices] IModelBinderFactory modelBinderFactory)
{
    var valueProvider = await CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ControllerContext);
    var modelMetadata = modelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(typeof(PersonName));
    var modelBinderFactoryContext = new ModelBinderFactoryContext
    {
        Metadata = modelMetadata,
        CacheToken = modelMetadata
    };
    var modelBinder = modelBinderFactory.CreateBinder(modelBinderFactoryContext);
    var modelBindingContext= DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext(ControllerContext, valueProvider, modelMetadata, new BindingInfo(), string.Empty);
    await modelBinder.BindModelAsync(modelBindingContext);
    var personName = modelBindingContext.Model as PersonName;
    // ...
    return Ok(personName);
}
```